# Problemas al implementar libreria SFML en VS Community

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, libreria, sfml

Quiero empezar a usar librerías, y quiero probar un simple código que requiere SFML, así que fui a la página oficial y descargue la versión C++ 17 2022 (yo tengo Visual Studio Community 2022 en la versión 17.7.2). Acá dejo el link: https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.6.0/.

Y por lo que leí, tenia que:

1. Descomprimir el archivo.
2. Abrir un proyecto de Consola Windows.
3. Ir a Propiedades/Directorios de VC++/General.
4. En Directorios de Archivo de Inclusión darle en Editar y poner la ruta de la carpeta "include".
5. Y luego en Directorios de Archivo de Biblioteca agregar la ruta de la carpeta "lib".
6. Despues, ir a Vinculador/Entrada y en Dependencias Adicionales escribir `sfml-graphics-d.lib;sfml-window-d.lib;sfml-system-d.lib`.

Y después de todo eso, escribir el código de prueba incluyendo: `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>`.

Que según esto, me saldría un error donde diría: "La ejecucion de código no puede continuar porque no se encontró `sfml-system-d-2.dll`. Este problema se puede solucionar reinstalando el programa.", así que tendría que copiar dicho archivo de la librería y pegarlo en la misma ruta donde estaba el archivo ejecutable del proyecto.

Sin embargo, sigue sin funcionar, y la verdad ya no encontré más ayuda, ¿Alguien tiene idea de como poder reparar este error?

Pdt: cuando intente la primera vez tener SFML lo hice mediante NuGet, pero me marcaba error aun instalado, pero no hice alguna configuración con este método, ¿debo de hacer una?

Acá esta el código (me lo dió ChatGPT) que quiero probar:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    // Crear una ventana
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Mover Cubo");

    // Crear un cubo
    sf::RectangleShape cube(sf::Vector2f(50.0f, 50.0f));
    cube.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    cube.setPosition(375.0f, 275.0f);

    // Bucle principal
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
        }

        // Mover el cubo con las teclas
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) {
            cube.move(-1.0f, 0.0f);
        }

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) {
            cube.move(1.0f, 0.0f);
        }

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) {
            cube.move(0.0f, -1.0f);
        }

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) {
            cube.move(0.0f, 1.0f);
        }

        // Limpiar la ventana
        window.clear();

        // Dibujar el cubo
        window.draw(cube);

        // Mostrar lo dibujado
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "*sigue sin funcionar*"? ¿no compila? ¿no enlaza? ¿no ejecuta? ¿no ejecuta bien?

Comment: Las DLLs no se van a copiar por defecto, búscalas y copialas en el mismo directorio donde se está generando el EXE o edita el proyecto para que las copie durante la compilación

Comment: La otra alternativa sería ver cómo tienes que enganchar la librería SFML para que forme parte del ejecutable. En ese caso ya no hará falta la DLL

Comment: @eferion La propia página de SFML indica cómo "*enganchar la librería SFML para que forme parte del ejecutable*", en el apartado de compilación estática. Entre otras cosas, hay que cambiar los compilados para que sean `*.-s.lib` o `*.-sd.lib` según compilación *release* o *debug*.

Answer (score 0):

El procedimiento debería estar bien. Asegúrate de tener los DLL en la carpeta donde se está ejecutando el programa o agregarlos al PATH.

Recuerda que debes hacer el mismo procedimiento para cada configuración del proyecto.

La otra opción que sugiere eferion es utilizar la versión estática de la librería así no necesitas ningún DLL. Basta con enlazar los .lib con la **s**.

Puedes ver un tutorial para que quede más claro. Mira el que quieras o busca otro.

- https://youtu.be/4fcTqmT0Hhg
- https://youtu.be/KRGPNi9mEMo

---

Puedes ver que hay 4 versiones de cada .lib, la **d** se refiere a **Debug**. Las versiones de este tipo pesan más porque no estan optimizadas y tienen símbolos de depuración. La **s** se refiere a **static**.